# How to assign manual shortcuts in Eclipse (Android & Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just started using eclipse and wonder if there is a way to find all the predefined shortcuts of eclipse(particularly android & Java) and assign them manually.

Comment: what do you mean with shortcut exactly? And assign them to what?

Comment: @user827992 For example I want to duplicate lines, so instead of copy paste, I want a simpler method which I have used in other softwares. I just wanted to knew is there is any combination or i will assign that manually

Comment: ok, i was thinking about other things, in this case the other replies can satisfy your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer,

Go to Windows Menu, Select Preference option,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys